# How do I deserialize XML that has 2 elements with the same name but the elements have different datatypes?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm working with an API that returns XML. If I call the API with one set of parameters, I will get back XML that looks something like this:

Type 1:

```
<root>
    <foos>
      <foo>some</foo>
      <foo>text</foo>
      <foo>here</foo>
    </foos>
</root>
```

But if I call the API with another set of parameters, I get back XML that looks something like this:

Type 2:

```
<root>
    <foos>
        <foo>
            <fooName>some</fooName>
            <fooId>1</fooId>
            <fooDate>11-8-2019</fooDate>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <fooName>text</fooName>
            <fooId>2</fooId>
            <fooDate>11-9-2019</fooDate>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <fooName>here</fooName>
            <fooId>3</fooId>
            <fooDate>11-10-2019</fooDate>
        </foo>
    </foos>
</root>
```

I would like to model that as a single C# object, if possible... so that I can deserialize either XML with something like this:

```
private root Deserialize(string xmlData)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlData))
    {                
        return (root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);                
    }            
}
```

I tried modelling the XML classes like this:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "foos")]
    public List<string> foos { get; set; }              
}
```

When the class looks like this, I can deserialize the xmlData for Type 1 (and i get a list of strings).  But when I try to deserialize the xmlData for Type 2, everything is null...

And if I model the XML class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "foos")]
    public List<Foo> foos { get; set; }              
}

[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fooName")]
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fooId")]
    public string FooId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fooDate")]
    public string FooDate { get; set; }               
}
```

Then I can deserialize the xmlData for Type 2 (and I get a list of complex objects).  But of course that doesn't work for the xmlData for Type 1.

Is there a way to model the classes in C# to handle both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to modify `Foo` so that it can capture both a text value and expected nested child elements by adding a string-valued property and marking it with [`[XmlText]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=netframework-4.8) like so:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlArray("foos")]
    [XmlArrayItem("foo")]
    public List<Foo> foos { get; set; }              
}

[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("fooName")]
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fooId")]
    public string FooId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fooDate")]
    public string FooDate { get; set; }               

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

1. [`XmlTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

   > Indicates to the `XmlSerializer` that the member must be treated as XML text when the class that contains it is serialized or deserialized.
2. `Foo` will now be able to bind to [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-mixed-content) nodes such as

   ```
   <foo>Some text<fooName>text</fooName>
     <fooId>2</fooId>
     <fooDate>11-9-2019</fooDate>
   </foo>
   ```
3. There are some errors in your existing `Root` and `Foo` data model that I corrected above, including:

   - `<fooName>`, `<fooId>` and `<fooDate>` are child elements not attributes, so their corresponding properties must be marked with [`[XmlElement]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netframework-4.8).
   - `foos` is bound to a sequence with an outer container element `<foos>` and inner sequential elements `<foo>` and so must be marked with [`[XmlArray]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YdATax).

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!  Also thank you for cleaning up the XML decorators in my foo-example, and for finding the correct search-term for this: "mixed content". I can't thank you enough!