# Trouble Deserializing/Serializing XML with Mixed Element Order in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am facing an issue while deserializing/serializing XML into a C# object. The XML structure has mixed order of elements, and I am encountering problems with elements that have the same name but different purposes. Here's a simplified version of my C# class:

```
public class Uientry
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "u")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "s")]
    public List<string> Strings { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "i")]
    public List<string> Integer { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "additional_data")]
    public Additional_data Additional_data { get; set; }
}
```

The issue arises when the XML has elements with the same name but different purposes, **and their order is not fixed. For example, the `<i>` elements (representing integers) can appear before and after `<s>` elements (representing strings), causing conflicts.**

Important:I want that the order of the elements stays the same after Serializing

**this is some of my xml code**

```xml
<uientry>
    <u>606917248</u><!-- ID (80 d2 2c 24) -->
    <s>root</s><!-- title -->
    <s>CampaignRoot</s><!-- title2 -->
    <i>0</i><!-- x offset -->
    <i>0</i><!-- y offset -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 1 -->
    <yes /><!-- uientry flag 2 -->
    <byte>1</byte><!-- uientry flag 3 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 4 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 5 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 6 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 7 -->
    <yes /><!-- uientry flag 8 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 9 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 10 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 11 -->
    <no /><!-- uientry flag 12 -->
    <yes />
    <unicode></unicode><!-- tooltip text -->
    <unicode></unicode><!-- tooltip id -->
    <i>0</i><!-- 00:00:00:00 --><!-- docking? -->
    <i>0</i><!-- 00:00:00:00 --><!-- docking x? -->
    <i>0</i><!-- 00:00:00:00 --><!-- docking y? -->
    <no />
    <i>0</i><!-- default state id -->
    <images count="1">
      <image>
        <u>606535040</u><!-- ID (80 fd 26 24) -->
        <s></s><!-- path -->
        <i>1280</i><!-- x size -->
        <i>960</i><!-- y size -->
        <no />
      </image>
    </images>
    <i>0</i><!-- 00:00:00:00 --><!-- mask image? -->
    <i>0</i>
    <states count="0">
    </states>
    <children count="0">
    </children>
    <additional_data type="none" />
</uientry>
```

How can I modify my C# class or use attributes to handle such a scenario? Is there a way to instruct the XML deserializer to consider the purpose of the element and handle it accordingly?

Comment: try online converter : https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/xml-to-csharp

Comment: THat being said, maybe [Xml Deserialization - Merging two elements into a single List<T> object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37307203/3744182) or [XML Serialization error - Invalid or missing value of the choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' of type '`ItemsChoiceType[]`'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51783203/3744182) might answer your question.  [How do I deserialize XML that has 2 elements with the same name but the elements have different datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58773967) might also apply.  Can't say for sure without a [mcve].

Comment: @dbc thank you for your response. I provided a minimal example of my code in the question.

Comment: Is the set of element names (`<u>`, `<i>`, `<yes>`, `<no>`, `<unicode>` and so on) known in advance, or could there be elements of any name?

Comment: the elements names `<u>`,`<i>` and `<unicode>` stay the same but the `<yes>` and `<no>` elements can switch like a bool

Comment: What does "can switch like a bool mean" Do you just mean `<yes>` can become `<no>`? Or do you mean `<yes>` and `<no>` can become `<true>` and `<false>`? Also, I'm not really seeing your original problem with elements have the same names but different data types -- all elements in your example with a given name all have the same data type (for example, all the `<u>` elements are numeric/ints ).

Comment: yeah i mean `<yes>` can become `<no>` and the  otherway around, sorry for my bad explanation.  Maybe the wording "purposes" fits more so like elements with the same name but different purposes.

Comment: This is starting to look like the kind of xml I would run away from as fast as I could ... If there is no way to know what a "No" is for other than hoping you get all your elements in the right order, and you are not getting all your elements in the right order ... isn't this hopeless? What you *should* be getting is something more like `<uientry_flag_4>no</uientry_flag_4>` rather than this mess...

Comment: Then what you have is a sequence of choice elements which can be handled using the one of the approaches from [Xml Deserialization - Merging two elements into a single List<T> object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37307203/3744182).  If you follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37309127/3744182) you should be all set.  That being said in practice it may not be easy to apply that answer, so do you need an answer tailored to your specific case?

Comment: @dbc thank you for your help for the yes/no thing but the order needs to stay the same of the elements not only for the yes/no but also for the integers and strings and the other stuff

Comment: @NickG - the yes/no thing was from a comment made by topsail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has a schema that includes a sequence of [*choice*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-choice) element.  A choice element indicates that one of a fixed set of elements -- `<u>`, `<i>`, `<yes>`, `<no>`, `<unicode>` and so on -- will occur in the XML.  `XmlSerializer` supports choice elements as is explained in [Choice Element Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa6z5baz.aspx):

> If individual choice elements' types differ along with their names, Xsd.exe applies only `XmlElementAttribute` attributes to a public member. If they differ only by name, Xsd.exe applies an `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute` in addition, and adds extra logic for making the choice.

Thus, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37309127/3744182) to *[Xml Deserialization - Merging two elements into a single List<T> object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37307203/3744182)*, you can either model this as a list of polymorphic types, or a pair of arrays of choice types and values.  Personally I think the first option is easier, so let's go with that.

First define some base type `UientryItem`, then for every element that might appear in `<uientry>`, create a subtype corresponding to that element, indicating the name via an [`XmlTypeAttribute.TypeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.typename?view=net-8.0) attribute property:

```
public abstract class UientryItem;

[XmlType("u"), XmlRoot("u")]
public class UientryId : UientryItem
{
    [XmlText] public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("s"), XmlRoot("s")]
public class UientryTitle : UientryItem
{
    [XmlText] public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("no"), XmlRoot("no")]
public class UientryNo : UientryItem;

[XmlType("yes"), XmlRoot("yes")]
public class UientryYes : UientryItem;

[XmlType("byte"), XmlRoot("byte")]
public class UientryByte : UientryItem
{
    [XmlText] public byte Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("unicode"), XmlRoot("unicode")]
public class UientryUnicode : UientryItem
{
    [XmlText] public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("i"), XmlRoot("i")]
public class UientryInt : UientryItem
{
    [XmlText] public int Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("images"), XmlRoot("images")]
public class UientryImages : UientryItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("count")]
    public int Count { get => Images?.Count?? 0; set { } }

    [XmlElement("image")]
    public List<UientryImage> Images { get; set; } = new();
}

[XmlType("image"), XmlRoot("image")]
public class UientryImage
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(UientryId)), 
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryTitle)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryNo)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryYes)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryByte)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryUnicode)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryInt)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryImages)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryStates)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryChildren)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryAdditionalData))]
    public List<UientryItem> Items { get; set; } = new();
}

[XmlType("states"), XmlRoot("states")]
public class UientryStates : UientryItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("count")] public int Count { get; set; }
    // TODO: fill in appropriate properties
}

[XmlType("children"), XmlRoot("children")]
public class UientryChildren : UientryItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("count")] public int Count { get; set; }
    // TODO: fill in appropriate properties
}

[XmlType("additional_data"), XmlRoot("additional_data")]
public class UientryAdditionalData : UientryItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")] public string Type { get; set; }
    // TODO: fill in appropriate properties
}
```

Next define `Uientry` as follows:

```
[XmlType("uientry"), XmlRoot("uientry")]
public class Uientry
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(UientryId)), 
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryTitle)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryNo)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryYes)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryByte)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryUnicode)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryInt)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryImages)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryStates)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryChildren)),
     XmlElement(typeof(UientryAdditionalData))]
    public List<UientryItem> Items { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And you will be able to deserialize your `<uientry>` using a `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Uientry))` e.g. as follows:

```
using var textReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Uientry));

var uiEntry = (Uientry)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
```

And the element order will be preserved via the order of items in the `public List<UientryItem> Items { get; set; }` list.

Notes:

- If you are sure that some of the elements occur at the beginning or end of the `<uientry>` element -- for instance, that `<additional_data>` always appears last -- then you can capture that with a separate property as you did in your original `Uientry` class.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3xHzMt).